# How to make a SVG interactive in flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg

So I have this **world map** SVG and what I want is that when someone clicks on a country, that particular country gets highlighted and I can extract that country's name. How to achieve something like this in flutter?

Here is the SVG that I'm looking forward to using:
https://simplemaps.com/resources/svg-world

Answer (score 0):

You could work with click coordinates:

- Assign every country an interval of coordinates
- Get click coordinates
- Loop through coordinate-intervals
- Find closest coordinate to click
- Get country where coordinate belongs to
- Show country-information on touch coordinates until new touch is registered

Highlighting the country wouldn't work this way. I believe there are librarys for working with vectors.